# iOS, Box2d & Cocos2d: How do I, Create a dynamic body, and then destroy it when it falls to the ground

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, physics

It sounds simple enough in the title, however for the last 3 days i've struggled to do what sounds like a simple thing.

The "MyContactListener.h/mm" method, as advised on the **Ray Wenderlich** tutorial followed [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/28606/how-to-create-a-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial-part-2), worked for a single object, however my game is going to produce several items at regular intervals rather than fixed in place at initiation as per the tutorial.

I ended up having an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when i tried to put the `objectBodyFixture` in an `NSMutibleArray` that held all the `b2fixture` objects created. My intention was to parse through them all on each `tick:` to look for contacts, and handle appropriately.

Now I'm at a loss for what to do. So just to clarify, I simply need to create falling objects from the sky that destroy when they hit my ground object.

I'm going to provide as much as I can here just in case its not as simple to do as it sounds... As you'll se I'm using the "MyContactListener.h/mm" as advised on the Ray Wenderlich tutorial followed [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/28606/how-to-create-a-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial-part-2).

---

The idea is to drop the created dynamic bodies from the sky at regular intervals, and then destroy them if they fall to hit the ground.

I have a ground object that I created as a static body during the init of the scene:

```
@implementation HelloWorldLayer
{
    CGSize size;
    b2Body *_groundBodyBottom;
    b2Fixture *_groundBottomFix;
    NSMutableArray *_objectFixtures;
}
-(id) init { if( (self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(50, 180, 220, 255)]) )
{
    // First instance setups
    size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    _objectFixtures = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Create The World
    b2Vec2 gravity = b2Vec2(0.0f, -8.0f); // -128.0
    _world = new b2World(gravity);

     // Create The Ground
     // Bottom
     b2BodyDef groundBottomBodyDef;
     groundBottomBodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
     groundBottomBodyDef.position.Set((size.width/2)/PTM_RATIO, 60/PTM_RATIO);
     _groundBodyBottom = _world->CreateBody(&groundBottomBodyDef);

     b2PolygonShape groundBottomShape;
     groundBottomShape.SetAsBox((size.width/2)/PTM_RATIO, 1.3);

     b2FixtureDef groundBottomShapeDef;
     groundBottomShapeDef.shape = &groundBottomShape;
     groundBottomShapeDef.density = 10.0f;
     groundBottomShapeDef.friction = 1.0f;
     groundBottomShapeDef.restitution = 0.0f;
     _groundBottomFix = _groundBodyBottom->CreateFixture(&groundBottomShapeDef);

     // Hand off repeating schedules
     [self scheduleUpdate];
     [self schedule:@selector(addAnObjectUpdate:) interval:1];

     // Create contact listener
     _contactListener = new MyContactListener();
     _world->SetContactListener(_contactListener);
}
```

As you can see the `addAnObjectUpdate` will fire every second...

```
-(void)addAnObjectUpdate:(ccTime)dt
{
    CCSprite *objectSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"myObject.png"];
    objectSprite.position = ccp(size.width/2,size.height *2);
    objectSprite.scale = 0.10;
    objectSprite.tag = 1;
    [self objectSprite z:30]; //z:30 overlaps clouds in scene

    b2BodyDef objectBodyDef;
    objectBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    objectBodyDef.position.set((size.width/2)/PTM_RATIO, (size.height + objectSprite.boundingBox.size.height)/PTM_RATIO);
    objectBodyDef.userData = (__bridge void*)objectSprite;
    _objectBody = _world->CreateBody(& objectBodyDef);

    int scalledPTMRatio = PTM_RATIO * 10; // Needed if the sprite image is scalled...
    int num = 8;
    b2Vec2 verts[] = {
        b2Vec2(-59.8f / scalledPTMRatio, -173.8f / scalledPTMRatio),
        b2Vec2(-5.9f / scalledPTMRatio, -199.5f / scalledPTMRatio),
        b2Vec2(53.8f / scalledPTMRatio, -174.9f / scalledPTMRatio),
        b2Vec2(63.1f / scalledPTMRatio, 198.3f / scalledPTMRatio),
        b2Vec2(-6.7f / scalledPTMRatio, 196.0f / scalledPTMRatio),
        b2Vec2(-53.8f / scalledPTMRatio, 144.7f / scalledPTMRatio),
        b2Vec2(-71.4f / scalledPTMRatio, -104.7f / scalledPTMRatio),
        b2Vec2(-66.4f / scalledPTMRatio, -160.6f / scalledPTMRatio)
    };
    b2PolygonShape objectShape;
    objectShape(verts, num);

    b2FixtureDef objectShapeDef;
    objectShapeDef.shape = & objectShapeDef;
    objectShapeDef.density = 1.0f;
    objectShapeDef.friction = 0.f;
    objectShapeDef.restitution = 0.8f;
    b2Fixture * objectShapeDef = _objectBody->CreateFixture(&objectShapeDef);
    [_objectFixtures addObject:(__bridge NSObject*)objectBodyFixture];  // Heres hoping to access them during the tick:
}
```

With all this in place, my tick: method is as follows:

```
-(void)tick:(ccTime) dt
{
    _world->Step(dt, 10, 10);
    // Check For Collissions
     NSLog(@"\n\n\nTick....");
     std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
    for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin(); pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos)
    {
        MyContact contact = *pos;

         for (NSObject *myObject in _objectFixtures)
        {
             if ((contact.fixtureA == _groundBottomFix && contact.fixtureB == (__bridge class b2Fixture *)(myObject)) ||
                (contact.fixtureA == (__bridge class b2Fixture *)(myObject) && contact.fixtureB == _groundBottomFix))
            {
                NSLog(@"myObject touched the ground!");
                [_hud changeLivesTo:[_hud livesRemaining] - 1];
            }
        } // For loop - Array
    } // For loop - contacts/collisions
}
```

Well I think this is all the relevant code for helping me solve this one, if theres anything more I can provide, to help improve the question, please let me know and I will update the question.

I'de really appreciate your help on this one, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would typically do it.

Use a set to store a list of bodies to destroy:

```
std::set<b2Body*> bodiesToDestroy;
```

Make a class that extends b2ContactListener and implements the BeginContact function, and set an instance of this as the contact listener for your world:

```
class MyContactListener : public b2ContactListener {

    virtual void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact) {
        if ( ... contact is between ground and falling body ... ) {
            bodiesToDestroy.insert( ... the falling body ... );
            ... do other necessary things, eg. change score etc ...
        }
    }

};
```

After stepping the world, destroy bodies in the list and then clear it:

```
world->Step( ... ); // contact listener is called inside here

for ( std::set<b2Body*>::iterator it = bodiesToDestroy.begin(); it != bodiesToDestroy.end(); ++it)
    world->DestroyBody( *it );
bodiesToDestroy.clear();
```

EDIT:
You can find more information about where these code snippets fit into the overall picture, at these pages:

http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-callbacks

http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/removing-bodies

Source code for the examples can be found here:

http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/sourcecode

Comment: Thank you for you answer, however I'm having some difficulty understanding 1) where to put the code you've provided, and 2) where the actual identification of the two specific objects take place. If you can add comments, add where to add the code, and explain what " ... contact is between ground and falling body ... " means, then I can mark this as an answer provided I understand it. Because if I can, and one can lol.... thanks

Comment: hmm... there is actually a lot of information and code samples about this all over the net already. My site is a good place to start :) www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut You can also take a look at the Box2D testbed examples which have a demonstration usage of every Box2D feature if you look around a bit.

Comment: I'm only really interested in doing my little bit to make stack overflow a better site by answering the questions here rather than making fellow users leave the site. If you have the information that I and other users in the future may need, the please feel free to include it in your answer above. Thanks

Comment: Understood. Yes, I do have information that others in the future may need, and I have already written the equivalent of a small book at my site. I don't see the need or have the time to repeat parts of it for questions on Stack Overflow when said other users can easily click a link to go see a full description for the generic case with a working source code example. To be more specific, I think these two pages are relevant: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-callbacks http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/removing-bodies and the source code is here: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/sourcecode

Comment: The check for "... contact is between ground and falling body ..." is what you have already posted, eg. `if (contact.fixtureA == _groundBottomFix && ...` where you check if one fixture is the ground and the other is on a falling body.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up simply adding a tag to the `b2FixtureDef.userdata` when creating the fixture. I used a `struct` to make my own object that I could put into the `b2FixtureDef.userdata` that would contain my tag, and anything else i needed. The `struct` looks like this:

```
struct MyUserData { 
    int myTag; 
};
```

Then when declaring the `b2FixtureDef i add this...

```
MyUserData *theGroundUserData = (MyUserData*)malloc(sizeof(MyUserData));  // USER DATA BIT
theGroundUserData->myTag = 3;
groundBottomShapeDef.userData = theGroundUserData;
```

...Saving my tag into a `MyUserData` object that i later check for in my tick:

```
std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin(); pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos)
{
    MyContact contact = *pos;

    if (contact.fixtureA->GetUserData() != NULL && contact.fixtureB->GetUserData() != NULL) {

        int fixtureNameA = ((MyUserData *)contact.fixtureA->GetUserData())->myTag;
        int fixtureNameB = ((MyUserData *)contact.fixtureB->GetUserData())->myTag;
        // Check for an apple colliding with the ground
        if ((fixtureNameA == 2 && fixtureNameB == 3) || (fixtureNameA == 3 && fixtureNameB == 2))
        {
            NSLog(@"Apple touched the ground");
            b2Body *bodyA = contact.fixtureA->GetBody();
            b2Body *bodyB = contact.fixtureB->GetBody();
            if (fixtureNameA == 2)
            {
                if (std::find(toDestroy.begin(), toDestroy.end(), bodyA) == toDestroy.end()) {
                    toDestroy.push_back(bodyA);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (std::find(toDestroy.begin(), toDestroy.end(), bodyB) == toDestroy.end()) {
                    toDestroy.push_back(bodyB);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```